# Logica en Consulta MySQL solo si se cumplen 2 condiciones

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

poseo el siguiente codigo:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM pedidos  WHERE usuario = '$usua' AND status_pedido = 'ESPERANDO' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
if ($result){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"" >
                <h3>
        LO SENTIMOS, USTED POSEE UN PEDIDO EN ESPERA        
                </h3>
            </div>';


} else { echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"" >
                <h3>
        AQUI SE IMPRIME UN FORMULARIO       
                </h3>
            </div>';}
```

La idea es que si se cumple la condicion 1 y la condicion 2 de resultados

La condicion `usuario = '$usua'` casi siempre va a mostrar resultados pero no necesariamente la condicion `status_pedido = 'ESPERANDO'` asi como esta siempre da resultados aun cuando la segunda condicion sea `"ENTREGADO"`

Quisiera saber si hay una forma de cambiar la forma de hacer la consulta a MySQL.

Comment: No entiendo cuál es el problema, o cuál es la pregunta, así como lo tienes, haya o no resultados imprimes lo mismo, entonces cómo lo diferencias?

Comment: Correcto asi como lo tengo imprime resultados, y lo que quiero es que de 'TRUE' si 'status_pedido = 'ESPERANDO'' pero si es diferente entonces de 'FALSE', voy a editar para graficar mejor lo que deseo.

Comment: Gracias @WilsonicX por la gentil correccion, saludos cordiales..!

Comment: Saludos amigo @JoseMHerreraV estamos para ayudar :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que **mysqli_query** devuelve un **True** o un **False** siempre y cuando la consulta se ejecute con exito, es decir solo te va a mandar un False cuando exista un error, lo que tu necesitas es saber si el número de filas es mayor a cero, es decir si existen registros con las condiciones que requieres para ello deberias de usar algo así:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM pedidos  WHERE usuario = '$usua' AND status_pedido = 'ESPERANDO' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        $rows =  mysqli_num_rows($result)
if ($rows > 0){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"" >
                <h3>
        LO SENTIMOS, USTED POSEE UN PEDIDO EN ESPERA        
                </h3>
            </div>';


} else { echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"" >
                <h3>
        AQUI SE IMPRIME UN FORMULARIO       
                </h3>
            </div>';}
```

Documentación: http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php